# Are points on the edge of a polygon inside the polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygons

This seems like a simple question but I did not find a clear answer to this by Googleing. For a simple polygon that is not self-intersecting, such as a triangle or square, if an arbitrary point is part of the edge of the polygon, is it said that it's inside the polygon (part of it) or not?

In other words, what type of inequality is used for polygons?

A source would be much appreciated for any answer.

Comment: It depends on the context, and sometimes it does not matter whether the boundary is included or not and it is conveniently ignored.

Comment: In typical circumstances a polygon means a closed polygon i.e. with edges. Otherwise the descriptions of a convex polygon as a convex hull of its vertices, or as a geometric realization of a cw-complex, or many others, become rather fishy. But check your context.